# UIDatePicker causing memory to rise

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I am creating an app that uses a date picker that is pictured below. In the simulator, each time the date picker is opened the memory continues to rise. Is there a way to dismiss the date picker so that it doesn't cause the memory to rise?

In the simulator I am exiting the calendar by clicking on the screen outside the calendar. I have included an example of the code used.

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func dateSelect(sender: UIDatePicker)
{
        date = datePicker.date
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
        currentDateString = dateFormat(date: date, format: "dd MMMM yyyy")
        currentDateStringForCard = dateFormat(date: date, format: "dd")

        saveDate()
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is your date picker initialized, how is it declared? Why isnt your date picker purged from memory when you dismiss the date picker by tapping outside? Increase in memory when you instantiate something is obvious and thats not a issue as long as memory is released and goes down when you release the object, but if thats not the case then you might have a memory leak

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. Yes I would like to remove it from memory when the date picker is dismissed by clicking on another part of the screen. How would I go about doing that? I have used: @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

Comment: Can you add all the code related to `UIDatePicker`

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. The question now contains all the code related to UIDatePicker. I also added the date picker to the view controller from the Library

Comment: If its added as an IBOutlet, it will remain in memory as long as the view (to which you have added it as subview I guess in your case its ViewController's View) is in memory, so memory should reduce and go back down as soon as you pop the ViewController, if thats the case you have nothing to worry, if you remove your ViewController and even after that if memory doesnt go down than its a issue

Comment: This view controller with the Date Picker is one of 3 view controllers linked to a tab bar controller, so that view controller (with the Date Picker added from the Library) isn't popped.